# Should product hierarchy be added to 1 or multiple dim tables?

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, dimensional-modeling

I have product hierarchy as follows:

Category

Sub category

Product

When does it make sense to have all these 3 columns in 1 table called Prooduct, or to make 3 tables - 1 for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should all be in a single table as they're logically related. Not only that, but data modelling is very different compared to OLTP. For instance, it is not uncommon to have a junk dimension which contains several columns which can all appear unrelated. Modelling is a very detailed subject and if you're after reading material, I can recommend Star Schema: The Complete Reference below.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Schema-Complete-Reference-Christopher-Adamson/dp/0071744320

The *only* time is makes sense to have these in separate tables and "snowflake" them is to take advantage of a little trick in PowerBI to suppress blanks in a slicer or matrix if you have a ragged hierarchy but this comes with drawbacks in having to write more complicated DAX down the line.

Comment: As well as having them all in one table you could also have them in aggregated dims if you had aggregated facts. For example you could have a dim that contained sub-category and category and another dim that contained just category. A dimensional model is not normalised so there is no issue, in theory, with duplicating data across tables